# serve same response just change url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am using React with webpack and Nodejs. Now when this is hit on network tab `http://localhost:8080/abc.js` after clicking a button then the abc.js file gets downloaded.

Now I want to change the url still server the abc.js file.

Example after clicking the same button `abc.js` file will get downloaded but now the url would be like `http://localhost:8080/abc.js/checking`

I tried this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.path = '/abc.js')
      req.path = req.url = '/checking';
    return next();
});
```

But its not working. What would be the correct aproach.

Comment: What is value of `req.path`?

Comment: @ViaTech `/abc.js`

Comment: You can use wildcards in routes according to the docs, so you can have multiple routes execute the same logic. But I'm confused, why not just change your inital link to `http://localhost:8080/abc.js/checking`? Normally 1 route handles the logic for the view, if you wish to redirect to the `abc.js/checking` url from the standard `abc.js` link that is possible using 2 routes as well. Why are you simply changing the path, what is the reason?https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: @ViaTech according to `checking` value I will modify the abc.js file and serve it. Will changing initial link work here?

Comment: You will have to return the contents of `abc.js` with the new route defined, but I don't see why not. Something returned like: `res.type('.js');` and `res.send("YOUR JS FILE");`